# VBA Spell Check in O365 (Access 2016) Crashing Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, office365, spell-checking, ms-access-2016

I ran the following code On Lost Focus event in Access 2010 with no problems.

```html
Dim strSpell
 strSpell = txtMyField
 If IsNull(Len(strSpell)) Or Len(strSpell) = 0 Then
 Exit Sub
 End If
 With txtMyField
 .SetFocus
 .SelStart = 0
 .SelLength = Len(strSpell)
 End With
 DoCmd.SetWarnings False
 DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling
 DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

After upgrading to O365 (Access 2016), the spell check works with no problems unless there's multiple spelling corrections. If the user choose to Change All or change more than 1 word Access crash and the user need to restart the program. I tried to change the code to run On Exit event but it didn't help. I also decompile the database and found no erros.

The only way I can run spell check is using the spell check on the ribbon. I hide the ribbon to prevent the users from messing around so this option is not going to work. Also, I would like to limit spell check to one field and force it after the user exit the field.

I'm guessing that Access is crashing because more than one correction trigger the event again and since spell Check is already running the program crash. Any idea how to fix it ?

UPDATED NOTES FROM COMMENTS

- In my testing I found that when you hit Enter several time when you
  type in the field, it cause the program to crash.
- Text field is LONG TEXT
- Form field is bound to text field

Comment: I doubt it's related but I would try changing `IsNull(Len(strSpell))` to `IsNull(strSpell)`

Comment: Are you running it in the txtField's or Form's LostFocus event

Comment: This code works fine for me in straight Access 2016 with multiple errors in both LostFocus event and in Command Button Click event. I'd suggest trying an Office Repair

Comment: I'm running the code in a bound form txtField event, not in a form event. Office repair didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's long text field. I ran the code in a new database with one table and one field in the form. I'm getting the same issue when I run the code. Running the spell check from the ribbon works fine with no errors or database crashing.

Comment: What is the length of the text field that you're editing? Does it crash when you spell check an entry with less than 255 characters?

Comment: The length of the text field changes all the time. I been testing it with different charters counts, some have more than 255. In my testing I found that when you hit Enter several time when you type in the field, it cause the program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repeat the hanging process "Not Responding" message with a Long Text field and 3500 characters and LOTS of items with 'spelling errors`.

Using your code it would crash with LostFocus code or even if I put it in a command button.

I started wondering if it was the whole text selection that was causing an error with how the spell checker tried to do its job - and whether that was even needed.

When I moved your code out of the `LostFocus` event and replaced it with this code in the `Exit` event it worked reliably

> EDIT: Moved code to Exit event and specified specific textfield

```
Private Sub txtMyField_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

    With txtMyField
        'If the textbox has data run the Spell Checker   
        If Len(.Value & "") > 0 Then
            .SetFocus
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Value)
            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
            .SelLength = 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for all you help so far! I tested your code and it works. Since we don't set the focus on the field, the spell check start checking all the fields in the form. Is there a way to stop it from moving between the field without setting the focus?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How would the spell checker know which field is being edited if you don't change the focus to it? In any case if this answers this particular question you should mark it as such and perhaps start a new question. Are you talking about looping thru all long text fields on the form, spell checking each and saving the edited data to the fields?

Comment: The issue with your code is that the spell check is checking all the text fields in the form. I need to limit it the spell check to one field.

Comment: Ah - okay - that makes sense - I only used one field on my test form

Comment: Okay - modified code to use Exit event - works on my two field form

Comment: Access still crashing. I also created a clean database with 3 fields and it crash. The spell check corrects the first 2 words and crash on the 3 word.

Comment: "Words for Access testing. blld" - Copy and paste this sentence 30 times and click enter after each sentence. When the spell check dialogue box opens choose Correct All. In the 3rd try Access is crashing.

Comment: Works fine with my 3000 character data set and your example data set. It does try to run spell check on every form field, but it does NOT crash. Do you have latest Office service pack?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm running the latest service pack. How do I check it?

Comment: I'm running the latest service pack per IT. Access crash when I run your code. No problems if I click the spell check in the ribbon. Very frustrating.